# Bootstrap card deck can't get card height to align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've used Bootstrap's card deck but i can't seem to make it align vertically.
One of the cards has shorter text and creates a mismatch, not sure how to fix it..

I should also mention that i want a 3 card display in that page on desktop and on mobile it stacks up vertically so that why i needed the extra margin in my css file.

```
<div class="container mw-100 h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img1.jpg" alt="img1" />
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Title 1</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero voluptas, vero voluptatibus odio nostrum facilis aut! Dolores, non accusamus. Sapiente et minus sint numquam. Labore laborum ut a commodi doloremque.
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" onclick="startGame()">Start</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img2.jpg" alt="img2" />
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Title 2<span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero voluptas, vero voluptatibus odio nostrum facilis aut! Dolores, non accusamus. Sapiente et minus sint numquam. Labore laborum ut a commodi doloremque.
                    </p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Start</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="img3.jpg" alt="img3" />
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Title 3<span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero voluptas, vero voluptatibus odio nostrum facilis aut! Dolores, non accusamus. Sapiente et minus sint numquam. Labore laborum ut a commodi doloremque.</p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Start</button>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As for other css there is only height that is needed to align the container itself and some margins along with the regular browser reset props.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.card {
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.row :first-child > .card {
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have your items aligned to the center `<div class="row h-100 align-items-center">` change it to top `<div class="row h-100 align-items-top">` This is in the 2nd line of your html. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/wp406n8d/4/

Also, you can get rid of this code:

```
.row :first-child > .card {
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
}
```

And I'm not completely sure if you were wanting this also, but you can simply add `height: 100%` to the `.card` class to make all of the cards the same height. See here:  https://jsfiddle.net/7ah6f4mo/

Comment: Forgot to explain some things, sorry :(

I want the 3 cards to be the main section of the page so it is centered in the middle, three in one row to be exact.

In the first fiddle i don't see how they are even, the shorter card is still shorter...

That margin-top part from my css is to give the first card a margin from the top on mobile devices it becomes vertical display, so unless you can suggest something else i still need that.

I actually tried the 100% height on the card but it didn't work, i guess since it was centered, but then the content inside isn't aligned to the others.

Comment: @John13  Ok I think I understand.  Why not align the items at the top, but add an `@media` for mobile which will then give the margin on the top of the first card when its in mobile view, but align all 3 perfectly when its not.  Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/oa9bgcsf/

Comment: I think my main issue is that my images are horizontal and not vertical like the one used in the fiddles so far, look what happens when a horizontal one is used
https://jsfiddle.net/40cz2eyp/
Try to pull the frame vertically and see all the extra space created and on mobile the margins don't work there are no gaps.

Comment: @John13 Got it.  Simply remove the `h-100` from the container div. I think this will solve your issue. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/xk8atpjL/

Comment: @John13 In response to my last comment, of removing `h-100` from the container div, you can then remove the `height: 100%` from the `.card` class which will give you this: https://jsfiddle.net/52hgk70d/

Comment: This is very good thank you @John, solved all issues but one. now that the alignment is top instead of center on the desktop version it only takes the top half of the page, how can i center it now? would try position but i need it responsive.

Comment: @John13 I don't think I can understand your question without some more context.  Can you make a jsfiddle of the issue? Or at least explain further?

Comment: Your last jsfiddle is just fine, imagine a full page version instead of a small frame
https://fiddle.jshell.net/xk8atpjL/show/?editor_console=

It aligns to the top now but i need it in the middle

Comment: Previous link is broken, i think i found a way to make it work
https://jsfiddle.net/xk8atpjL/show/

Comment: Just noticed that on desktop it also doesn't align because it depends on the content size, see image:
https://i.ibb.co/xFN684n/Screenshot-20200614-142700.png

Comment: @John13 Try something like this then: https://jsfiddle.net/xpad4r2o/

Comment: So close! , the problem now is with the card height: 100%, without it the height  of the cards doesn't match but with it, there are no margins between the cards on mobile :\

Comment: Also i find it strange that container2 works while using container mh-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center which should be exactly the same, doesn't work...
https://jsfiddle.net/02ucjwL4/1/

Comment: @John13 Then change the height to auto when its in mobile view using the `@media` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/69gLvt0m/